# Virtualenvwrapper environment variables when running crons

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm running a basic cron that requires environment variables which I've set up using `virtualenvwrapper`. The environment variables are set up in `/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/activate`

When I run the command `cd /home/ubuntu/test_script && /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/python3 my_script.py` the script runs as intended with no errors. The script imports an environment variable and prints it.

However, when I run the same script through a cron ( `* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test_script && /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/python3 my_script.py`) I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_script.py", line 4, in main
    print(os.environ['SOME_ENV_VARIABLE'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SOME_ENV_VARIABLE'
```

When I run the following I don't seem to have any issues

```
~$ /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/python3
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['SOME_ENV_VARIABLE']
'my_env_variable_value'
```

Am I missing something obvious, do I have some issue with virtualenvwrapper's configuration or is there a catch to running crons in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running python from the virtualenv (`/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/python3`) allows access to the venv `site-packages` but it doesn't activate the venv. If you have something unusual in `bin/activate` you have to source it every time you need it:

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test_script && . /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/activate && /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/python3 my_script.py
```

Comment: And if the env *doesn't* set this variable for you then your question is barking up the wrong tree, and you just need to set it explicitly for your `cron` job.

Comment: The question says: *The environment variables are set up in `/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testcron/bin/activate`*

Comment: @phd It looks like `source` doesn't work. You need to replace it with `.` instead. Otherwise, it worked great. Thanks for the help

Comment: Fixed `source`.