# How do I run a cronjob with a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv

Usually I SSH into my EC2 instance and run:

`source MYVENV/bin/activate`

How do I set my cronjob to activate the virtual environment? My Django script requires ENVIRONMENT variables that are stores in ~/.bash_profile

I tried following the steps here to no avail

[Cron and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * root source /home/ec2-user/MYVENV/activate && python /home/script.py
```

This is my current setup above.

I get this following error in the log:

/bin/bash: root: command not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193147/7976758 In your case something unusual is in `~/.bash_profile` so source it before running the script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcron%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+variables

Answer (score 17):

create a shell script 
eg scripts.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/MYVENV/bin/activate
python /path/to/file/script.py
```

Then in cron put

```
*/1 * * * * bash /path/to/shell/script/scripts.sh
```

The script will load all your environment variables and execute from the python in your environment

Answer (score 7):

you can just run the python interpretor from your environment directly eg

```
MYENV/bin/python script.py
```

to find out what is the directory to your environment python interpretor, change into the virtual env then run

```
which python
```

in your case, this should become

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/MYVENV/python /home/script.py
```

Comment: This issue with this is it doesn't activate my environment variables

Comment: in that case you need to add the path of python environment to the path ie. export PATH=/home/ec2-user/MYVENV:$PATH

Answer (score 2):

you can create a single wrapper bash script for executing your Django script. See the example below.

```
#!/bin/bash -l       // this should pick up your ~/.bash_profile environment variables

cd /path to project dir/   // set it up if your project is not in python path

source /Users/<user>/.virtualenvs/dslab/bin/activate // this activates your environment 

python /home/script.py   // run your script
```

Comment: Do I put this in a bash script, then run it?